For each employee need to get the sum of values based on their start date every month
I have two tables.
Table 1:



emp
startdate




010
15/02/2022


011
21/05/2022


012
04/012/2022



I need to have additional columns :startdate1 and enddate
which should look like:



emp
startdate
startdate1
enddate




010
15/02/2022
15/02/2022
14/03/2022


010
15/02/2022
15/03/2022
14/04/2022


010
15/02/2022
15/04/2022
14/05/2022



Till we reach the current month.



emp
startdate
startdate1
enddate




010
15/02/2022
15/05/2024
14/06/2024



The same should happen for the next employee 011
so and so forth until the last employee in the table1.
Table 2:
columns:
Emp#, attend date, hrs,
In SQL I am looking for a iterative query where for each employee from their start date, should get the total hours this should happen until the current date. and when there are no values it should return or NULL.
Example: employee 010 start_date is 15/02/2022;
15/02/2022 starting attend_date; Each attend date say has hours
15/02/2022 --> 6
16/02/2022 --> 8
14/03/2022 --> 8
from 15/03/2022 to 14/04/2022
18/03/2022 --> 4
20/03/2022 --> 8
23/03/2022 --> 6
from 15/04/2022 to 14/05/2022
22/04/2022 --> 4
02/05/2022 --> 7
10/05/2022 --> 8
so between 15/02/2022 and 14/03/2022 the total hours is 22;
so between 15/03/2022 and 14/04/2022 the total hours is 18;
so between 15/04/2022 and 14/05/2022 the total hours is 19;
sample data:
employees will have hours on workings in that month between 15/02/2022 to 14/03/2022; and so on and so forth every month from their start date
employee 1 started on 15/02/2022 so need sum hours between startdate and same day-1 next month.



emp
startdate
Enddate
Hours




010
15/02/2022
14/03/2022
22


010
15/03/2022
14/04/2022
18


010
15/04/2022
14/05/2022
19



Thanks in Advance

Can you please add some formatting? And please provide a sample structured table. I can't understand what problem you are trying to solve. Have a look at this: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Tips for asking a good Structured Query Language (SQL) question.

Start date logic:
First check whether the attendance date is less than 15th or not. If it is, then subtract that number of days from it to get the previous month. Then hard code day 15 to it. If date is from 1 to 14 then directly hard code day 15th to that month, year.
End Date Logic:
If date is between 1st to 14th then directly hard code 14 to month, year. If not then first hard code date to 15 of that month, year and then add 20 days to it to get the next month, year and then hard code day to 14th.
Below is the query (I used Hive database and HQL). You can change syntax or commands acc to your database:
att_date is attendance date.
select emp_id, start_date, end_date, sum(w_hours) as total_hours from (
select *,
case when cast(substring(att_date,1,2) as int)<15 then 
concat('15',substring(from_unixtime(unix_timestamp(date_sub(from_unixtime(unix_timestamp(att_date,'dd/MM/yyyy'),'yyyy-MM-dd'),cast(substring(att_date,1,2) as int)),'yyyy-MM-dd'),'dd/MM/yyyy'),3))
else concat('15',substring(att_date,3)) end as start_date,
case when cast(substring(att_date,1,2) as int)<15 then 
concat('14',substring(att_date,3)) 
else concat('14',substring(from_unixtime(unix_timestamp(date_sub(from_unixtime(unix_timestamp(concat('15',substring(att_date,3)),'dd/MM/yyyy'),'yyyy-MM-dd'),-20),'yyyy-MM-dd'),'dd/MM/yyyy'),3)) end as end_date 
from emp_work_hrs e) calcultd_tbl 
group by emp_id, start_date, end_date;


Hello Abhinav - Thanks for your answer. Sorry, If my instructions on the query were not clear. I need a series of monthly dates for each employee based on their start date; and then need to the the sum of hours on attend dates falling between those monthly ranges. we can generate monthly range for all employees in a temp table and then join and sum the values where attend_date falls between those dates with a condition emp-_start_date = min(attend_date).

I am sorry but I can't understand what you are trying to achieve in the above comment, what would be the structure of temp table and I don't think above joining condition would work. Please provide sample structure of all your input tables.
Also, above my query, definitely, is giving exactly same result that you are asking in excel format of your output records for your input data.

I have updated the query. I have added table1 and what is required from table1. Once we sort the table 1 to generate additional monthly rows  the we can use it table 2.
